# Triangle in GLUT wont change color on keyboard event

Tags: c++, glut

When i press "a" on keyboard triangle wont change color. It always draw triangle with default colors. And letter "q" for exit works.
So I wont when i press "a" to triangle change color, but this code don't work

I use GLUT and C++ programming language.

```
class color      // function of wanted color
{
    public:
        float boja;

    color()
    {
        boja=0.2;
    };

    void setBoja()
    {
        this->boja=1;
    };

    float GetBoja()
    {
        return boja;
    };
};

color colori;       // global variable colori

void display()      // function that display elements
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    triangle(colori.boja);

    glFlush();
}

void keyCB(unsigned char key, int x, int y)       // keybord function
{
    if( key == 'q' )
        exit(0);
    if( key == 'a' )
        colori.setBoja(); // this part dont change color.

}
```

My triangle function is defined as:

```
void triangle(float x) 
{
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   glColor3f(x, 0, 0);
   glVertex3f(-0.75, -0.75, 0.5);
   glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
   glVertex3f(0.75, -0.75, 0);
   glColor3f(0, 0, x);
   glVertex3f(0, 0.75, 0);
   glEnd();
}
```

Comment: How is triangle function defined and implemented?

Comment: This is triangle function:
    `void triangle(float x)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(x, 0, 0); glVertex3f(-0.75, -0.75, 0.5);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0.75, -0.75, 0);
        glColor3f(0, 0, x); glVertex3f(0, 0.75, 0);

        glEnd();
    }`

Comment: What did you call default color? Is it everything red? Did you call `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)`?